# Python Multiprocessing: Reloading module in child effecting parent

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-module

I feel like I should preface this question with the following statement: **I know that reloading  modules in python is frowned upon**. It's more of me tinkering around with Python and doing something just to prove that I can.

Say I have this bit of code in a main file:

```
def reloadFoo():
    lastReloadedTime = time.time()
    while True: 
      if os.stat(foo.__file__).st_mtime > lastReloadedTime: 
         lastReloadedTime = time.time()
         reload(foo)
```

and foo.py contains

```
def printMe():
    print "Yo ho yo ho"
```

If I call `reloadFoo()`, it will forever reload the module if it's been modified since the last time it's been reloaded. But how do I make this work as a background function of sorts?

I looked into multiprocessing so I had something like this in main:

```
import foo

def reloadFoo():
....
reloadProc = multiprocessing.Process(target=reloadFoo)
reloadProc.start()
...
while True:
   foo.printMe()
   time.sleep(20)
```

but it looks like if I change foo.py's printMe to print "A Pirate's Life for Me", it reloads the module, but doesn't "ripple" up to the parent process (and therefor future children): the main loop still prints "Yo ho yo ho"

I tried working with sending one end of a Pipe into reloadFoo, but I still had to call reloadFoo() within the main's while loop (which defeats the purpose of it having a child process to begin with, I guess).

Actual question: Is there a way for a child process to reload a module and it also get reloaded in the parent's process (and future children)?

Comment: What you actually need is file system event notification. You will find one library offering that at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog . On that page there is also a list of alternatives.

Comment: There's no easy way to have a child process change parts of the parent process's namespace. But why use a process here? You could easily use a thread instead, since the work you're doing is not terribly CPU intensive. Though, I guess the way you've written it, the `reloadFoo` function will thrash around a lot polling the filesystem to see if the file has changed. I suggest adding a short `sleep` to the infinite loop!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child process cannot directly affect its parent in this way very easily.  Add Python to the mix and it's practically impossible to do in a way that will do what you want.

You say you know that reloading modules is frowned upon, ant that you're just "tinkering around", but then you go on to say *Actual question: Is there a way for a child process to reload a module and it also get reloaded in the parent's process (and future children)?*

So since you've asked the question anyway, I'm going to give the answer you don't want anyway, because Stack Overflow is not just about the original questioner :-)

Reloading modules isn't frowned upon because of aesthetics; reloading modules is frowned upon because in any real system, reloading a module is unlikely to give you what you want, **even if you *aren't* trying to do it from a different process**.

For example, let's make a simple module called reloadme.py:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(self) is type(other) and self.value == other.value
```

It has a single class definition in it, and one of the things this class can do is allow instances of it to see if they are equal to other instances of it.  (This itself is rather unPythonic, because it's not using duck typing, but it's still a very simple way to illustrate real-world problems that *will* crop up in systems of any size.)  So let's use this module:

```
>>> import reloadme
>>> x = reloadme.MyClass()
>>> y = reloadme.MyClass()
>>> reload(reloadme)
>>> z = reloadme.MyClass()
>>> x == y
True
>>> x == z
False
```

Even though you've successfully reloaded the *module*, there are still bits and bobs of the old one hanging around the system.  Cleaning them up is *really* painful and time-consuming, and *not* cleaning them up will cause you the sorts of debugging headaches that make you question your own sanity.

Still, there *may* be good reasons to do this, e.g. systems that cannot go down, ever.  But it's not an easy thing to do, and most of the time, it's not very productive.